# How to align elements in the second `<td>` to top left when first `<td>`'s height is greater than second `<td>`

Tags: html, css

when the height of the first `<td>`is greater than the second `<td>`, contain text of second `<td>` is aligned to center. I want that text or elements of the second `<td>` to be aligned to top left when the first `<td>`'s height is greater than second.

How can i do it using `css`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:200px">some text1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        some text2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: top` to the td tag if you want to align text in all td elements to top.

If you just want to align the text in the second element use

`table tr td:nth-child(2)` instead of `table tr td`. nth-child applies the rule only to the 2nd td element.

Read more over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
table tr td{ 
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align:top
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>some text1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        some text2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
table td:nth-child(2) {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: it worked. could you please explain what does "nth-child(2)" do?

Comment: nth-child(2) select only the second td element. It's a css selector.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) you can read more about child selectors.